# SQL Statement running extreamly Slow

Tags: sql-server-2008

Okay I have look through several posts about SQL running slow and I didn't see anything similar to this, so my apologies if I missed one. I was asked about a month ago to create a view that would allow the user to report what hasn't been billed yet, and the SQL is joining 4 tables together. One is 1.2 million records ish. the rest are between 80K - 250K. (Please note that this should only return around 100 records after the where statements).

```
SELECT C.Cltnum + '.' + C.CltEng AS [ClientNum], 
              C.CPPLname, 
              w.WSCDesc, 
              MIN(w.Wdate) AS [FirstTDate], 
              w.WCodeCat, 
              w.WCodeSub, 
              SUM(w.Wbilled) AS [Billed], 
              SUM(w.Whours * w.Wrate) AS [Billable Wip], 
              sum(ar.[ARProgress]) AS [Progress], 
              w.Winvnum,
       --     dbo.GetInvoiceAmount(w.Winvnum) AS [InvoiceAmount],
              SUM(cb.cinvar) AS [AR Balance]
FROM    dbo.WIP AS w 
                     --Never join on a select statement
                     --join BillingAuditCatagoriesT bac on w.WCodeCat = bac.Catagory and w.WCodeSub = bac.Subcatagory
                     INNER JOIN dbo.Clients AS C ON w.WCltID = C.ID
                     JOIN dbo.ClientBuckets AS cb on c.cltnum = cb.cltnum 
                     JOIN dbo.AcctsRec AS ar on ar.arapplyto = w.[Winvnum]
-- WHERE w.wcodecat = '1AUDT'     

GROUP BY C.Cltnum, C.CltEng, C.CPPLname, w.WCodeCat, w.Wdate, w.Winvnum, w.WCodeSub, w.WSCDesc
```

so, where I think there may be a problem is that Category is a varchar it is xat, ACT, BID and there are about 15 different Category. this is the same as SubCat. you will notice that there are 3 functions on this and they are GetJamesProgress Which is = (SELECT sum(Amount) From Progress Where inv = w.invnum) and the same with GetInvoiceAmount and GetJamesARBalance. I know that this is bad to do but when I join by invoice number it takes even longer than with out them.

Please help thanks so much!

Comment: View the query plan first (and include such in questions). If it looks terrible, first try to update the statistics, then look again. If it still looks terrible, ensure there are appropriate indices (e.g. over the invoice number). And if the functions are suspect, simply try the query with them not present - however the statement "when I join by invoice number it takes even longer than with out them" makes me suspect the issue is simply with a bad query plan (and not related to said functions).

Comment: What are `GetJamesProgress` and `GetInvoiceAmount` and `GetJamesARBalance`?  They appear to be functions which can potentially have terrible performance.

Comment: This statement should generate a syntax error: where clause is after group by.

Comment: I will Look at the query and copy and past from there.The "Get" are functions that I have written. I can post exactly what they are today. sorry I didn't do that.

Comment: I had to change the code above as it wouldn't let me re enter it in here please see the above code...